# showing sums across all rows in sharepoint designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i create custom dataview ,i want to display the sum of all rows,i use xslt value like this:
select= "format-number(sum/dsqueryresponse/rows/row/@column"/>
it work fine but it display only the count of the current page. 
how to do to show sums across all rows and not just the current page